# Problems with Urllib2/beautiful soup not scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm pretty new to Beautiful soup but I have noticed that when I run this code a good amount of the time soup.prettify is not printing anything out. I've checked to make sure the page is correct but still no luck. Any ideas?

```
URL = "http://www.whoscored.com/Search/?t="
print "toURL: %s" %(URL)
request = urllib2.Request(URL)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
print soup.prettify()
```

Comment: This is probably because `whoscored.com` doesn't want web-scrapers to scrape the data on the site. Study [`Terms of Use`](http://www.whoscored.com/TermsOfUse) and make sure you are doing a legal thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the **User-Agent** to get the response.
Always use `print response.info()` and check out the **Content-Length** of response in these kind of cases to debug what's wrong.

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
print soup.prettify()
```